# SQL has query size limit?

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to make a select on my sql database who when each element is checked on code the query receives in WHERE clausure one more `OR name LIKE expression` and it works, but when i try to select more than 23 elements its not works, anybody knows if sql have a limit size for the query or something else?

the query looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE x% OR name LIKE y% OR name LIKE ...`(23x)

i cannot change this to something like `WHERE name IN (x,y,z)` :(

Comment: what error you can see? can you please put some more details?

Comment: Are you running your query using PHP ?

Comment: This answer is **highly** dependent on the DBMS. Which one do you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: i trying to generate a output error but im failing. but when i make the select with 22 elements it works, when i try to 23 it returns a empty table

Comment: how you are storing this query string in a variable. What is the size of that variable?

Comment: `{"Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'PEXTRON'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'PEXTRON'."}` (PEXTRON092 is a value of one of the checkboxes) seens like the string is too small, how can i fix that?

Comment: I found a error.

im using `Declare @SqlString nvarchar(2500)` and the query who i made is bigger than 2500, so, just changed to `Declare @SqlString nvarchar(max)` and fixed :)

Comment: Great, I was asking you to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general answer to the question of database limits.  Yes they have limits.  They vary with the RDBMS but these are the ones I've stumbled across over the years.

1. Lists can have only x elements.  It's applicable in this sort of syntax.

   where myfield in (1,2,3, etc)

With oracle 10, the limit is 1000.  With sql server it's somewhere around 2500.

1. The query itself can only have so many characters.  This was your original question and while it appears that this was not your specific problem, I've seen it happen with sql server.
2. A query will accept only x parameters.  I've exceeded this with ColdFusion/SQL Server but I can't remember what the limit was.

Comment: tnx, this awnser the question.
and my problem is other thing, but as solved too :)